# Is there a way to revert changes that git made to my local files?

Tags: git, github

I had been having issues pushing my files to a repository and it told me to compare using pull. So when I did it suggested rebase and it deleted all sorts of progress. Is there any reverting the changes?

Comment: "compare using pull"? `pull` is used to merge remote changes into your local branch, it does not compare anything. Did you stash any changes before rebasing or did you delete your local changes during conflict resolution? (`git stash list` shows your stash entries). General advice: as long as something is not committed, it is easy to lose it. Always commit important code (commit early and often)

Comment: And did you use `git pull` or `git rebase` (or `git pull --rebase`)? It's unclear from your question

Comment: I highly recommend have at least a master and development branch. If you are doing all your work on a single branch you are not only in danger of having lots of headaches if the branch is corrupted but you aren't taking advantage of a lot that git has to offer.

Comment: i used git pull --rebase

Comment: I don't understand git that well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you forced a pull you should have been asked by git to commit or stash any changes, so you should be able to revert back to that commit, or unstash what you stashed.

If you forced a pull or rebase with uncommited and changes not push to remote branch you are not using git correctly and I suggest reading through some git documentation and doing some tutorials to understand generally accepted practices so you don't encounter data loss in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is. If you pushed it to repo that is. Github is a version control system that is the whole point. Here is a photo explaining where to find previous commits and you can get the code from there.
[image: Github commits history]

There is also the ability to use the pull command from the terminal if you are experienced.